# UI is not updated after replacing an item in list when using notifyListeners()

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm using the Provider package for state management in a Flutter app and I have a list model extending ChangeNotifier.
In the list model there is a method to replace a certain element in the list like this:

```
class MyListModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<MyListItem> _myList = [];
  
  void replace(Data data) {
     int index = _findById(data.id);
     if(index == -1) {
       return;
     }
     _myList[index] = MyListItem(data);
     log("After replace: " + _myList.toString());
     notifyListeners();
  }

  void add(MyListItem myItem) {
    _myList.add(myItem);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void remove(MyListItem myItem) {
    _myList.remove(myItem);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This is the lis and the list item class where the provider is consumed:

```
class _MyListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Data _data;
  const _SelectUpcomingMealList(this.upcomingMeal);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return MyListItem(_data);
        }
    );
  }
}

class MyListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Data _data;

  MyListItem(this._data);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MyListModel>(
        builder: (context, myListModel, children) => ListTile(
          title: Text(_data.name),
          subtitle: Text(_data.description),
          trailing: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onTap: () => replaceMyItem(myListModel, context),
        )
    );
  }

  void replaceMyItem(MyListModel myListModel, BuildContext context) {
    myListModel.replace(_data);
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
```

For some reason the UI is not updating and the replaced item is not displayed, the old item is visible. The logging shows that the list is properly updated (the index also properly calculated), the replaced element is there, but the UI does not update.

The `add()` and `remove()` methods work, in these cases the UI properly reflects the change.

Is there something I'm missing in case of an item being replaced?

Comment: You should use Key in your UI. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Comment: How do you consume this provider?

Comment: @Kantine thanks for the response, but I'm using a stateless widget for the list and it's items, since the state comes from the list model

Comment: @PeterKoltai I added the list and list item code, you can see the Consumer there

Comment: @holparb You should use the data you get from the `Consumer` to build the widget, e.g. `myListModel.` instead of `_data` as you do now.